# Removing the PHP Mailer sent header

Tags: javascript, php, email

I am still new to php, but I am struggling a bit with a headache. My emails get send perfectly, but after I send the email, a seperate webpage shows up showing all the email header information. I want to know how do I go about removing it? I don't want everyone to see where their email is sending to, or even getting this web page to show. I already tried taking the page to go directly to another page after the message sending was successful so for a split second the header shows. I just want my javascript alert to appear that the message has been sent successfully and that there will be an attendance shortly.

So how do I go about removing the header?

The header looks like something like this on the web page:

```
2014-06-24 18:21:01 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 
2014-06-24 18:21:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2014-06-24 18:21:04 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWFyaWV0amllLmRhdmVsMjRAZ21haWwuY29t 
2014-06-24 18:21:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: bWFyaTN0amll 
2014-06-24 18:21:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2014-06-24 18:21:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2014-06-24 18:21:13 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 20:20:52 +0200 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: blah@gmail.com 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: BLAH 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Test7 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <5ee336b4eab3be7e72dbce2097197e26@localhost> 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.8 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Test7 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2014-06-24 18:21:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2014-06-24 18:21:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Where's the code driving this script?

Comment: Yeah without seeing the code that's sending the mail there's no way to tell what's causing that output to go to the browser. You're better off fixing the output cause than blocking it, but in a pinch you could try calling `ob_start()` before you send the mail, and `ob_end_clean()` after sending it to block the output. Again, the better option is to identify what is outputting it, not block the output.

Comment: Thank you Devon, you just answered my question :)

Comment: $mail->SMTPDebug = false;

Devon answered my question. Thank you. I have not seen it.

Comment: @user3752173 I added it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMTPDebug being true will output these headers as it is a development feature for PHPMailer.

For production use, always make sure debug features are off.

`$instance->SMTPDebug = false;`

in this case.